# RecyclerView individual viewTypes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display many [CardViews] within a [RecyclerView]. 
Therefore I am using an adapter that extends

> RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerView.ViewHolder >

Everything works fine so far.

But now, I want to populate the CardView with different widgets(checkboxes, textviews, buttons.. ) in different order, dependent on the data of the current dataset position. Defining a ViewHolder class for every possible combination of the widgets order is not an option due too many possibilities. 
I managed it already with two RecyclerView-Adapters. One for the RecyclerView "list" and one for populating the CardView inside each item.

But that leads to bad performance.

So I came back to use only one RecyclerView and one Adapter.

But, how to populate each CardView in a good way then? Thank you for your help!

**Update1:**

This is my current and result [updated_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiaCg.png). Looks "fine" so far but is achieved not in a proper way. 
I did it as following:
Setting an Adapter (OuterAdapter) to the recyclerView, that holds each CardView:

```
public class OuterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>  {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        rviewHolder = (RviewHolder) holder;
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        rviewHolder.rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        innerAdapter = new VHAdapter(context, questionList);
        rviewHolder.rv.setAdapter(innerAdapter);

    }
.
.
.
}
```

Now, every Item has its own "VHAdapter" which fills the CardViews like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, final int position) {

    switch (h.getItemViewType()) {
        case ONLY_HEADER_TEXT:
            HeaderTextHolder holder = (HeaderTextHolder) h;
            holder.tv.setText(q.getText());
            break;

        case ANSWER_TYPE_NUMBER:
            NumberHolder nh = (NumberHolder) h;
            nh.tv.setText(q.getText());
            nh.et.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                    tempAnswer.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString()));
                    tempAnswer.setQuestionType(Question.ANSWER_TYPE_NUMBER);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
            .
            .
            .
```

What I am trying to do now is getting rid the VHAdapter. But that means, I'd have to manually add widgets to ViewHolders rootLayout at OuterAdapter's onBindViewHolder.. Is that correct?

Comment: When you override the onBindViewHolder() method in your adapter it takes the item position as an argument.  This is where you could check the position and modify your views as necessary.  I don't think I could say more without more information about what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks: I updated my question, hope this helps for better understanding.

Comment: Do you only need 4 variations in layout (as in your screenshot) or more?  If only 4,  I'd be inclined to just make 4 different layouts.  If not, maybe you could just hide "view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)" stuff away when it is not needed in the original 'outer' view holder.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are almost unlimited variations possible. The screenshot only depicts sample data.